# Python, twisted code returns in the middle of this function

Tags: python, json, twisted

I am working on a project that uses Twisted, I am trying to debug my code which just returns in the middle of function with no errors.

Here is the function

```
def printData(self, response, client_id, limit):
    json_data = json.loads(response)
    results = json_data["results"]
    # Limit results
    json_data["results"] = results[0:int(limit)]
    logging.info("API Response: {0}".format(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)))
    msg = self.factory.clients[client_id]["msg"]
    full_response = "{0}\n{1}\n\n".format(msg, json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    self.transport.write(full_response)
```

response is a json text, client id is something like wikip.cs.info.com and limit is 20.

The function just does not execute after 2nd line and does not show any errors. Any idea why this would be the case ?

Comment: Are you sure it is not raising an exception that is being hidden somewhere outside this function?

Comment: not as far as I know. I am new to python and twisted, so I am not even sure how can I check that. But program resumes as normal after that and waits for next imput, and does not output what I needed for this one.

Comment: how do you know it returns after 2nd line ? You code here doesn't show what you tried to diagnose the problem

Comment: I added bunch of outputs in between lines. And the output after  linejson_data["results"] = results[0:int(limit)] was not being executed. So line 3 is the last line to be executed, not 2. My mistake.

Comment: Put a break point right before the "the code stops working" and check your variables.  So in your case, you would put ``import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`` after line 2 or 3.  Then see what happens when you enter ``logging.info("API Response: {0}".format(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)))``.  Maybe the ``json.loads()`` is taking too long. Does the client that's connected to your app get ``full_response``?

Comment: Please include a http://sscce.org so that we can actually *run* this function rather than guessing what's wrong with it.